# My Stack Overflow account is detached from my other Stack Exchange accounts

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, user-accounts, openid

I can't log into my Stack Overflow account using Google Mail. When I do I get this error message:

[image: SO1]

When I log in using another Stack Exchange account and check the list of communities that I'm on, Stack Overflow doesn't show up:

[image: SO2]

When I visit Stack Overflow (still logged in via the other StackExchange account) I get the **Join this community** button as if I'm not:

[image: SO3]

Trying to join also fails.

Visiting my [Stack Overflow user page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6647153/ibrahim-mahrir) shows that I'm currently on only one StackExchange community, the others are missing. It's as if my Stack Overflow account is detached from my other Stack Exchange accounts and I can't access it anymore.

**How to fix this? How can I log into my Stack Overflow account? How can join those Stack Exchange accounts back?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I go to your [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/8904997/ibrahim-mahrir?tab=accounts) starting from your account here on Meta.SE, I see your SO account -- among several others.  If I go to your SO account from there, though, I see what you see -- an SO account with no other accounts showing.  If I go from *there* to your network profile, I reach a [different network profile that shows no accounts](https://stackexchange.com/users/8248346/ibrahim-mahrir?tab=accounts).  (Look at the URLs; the user numbers are different.)

I don't know if it would have caused this, but have you ever had other credentials on either side that you then removed?  (For example, maybe you deleted an old OpenID credential?)  I'm speculating here, but if you only ever logged in to SO using one credential and only ever logged in to other sites using the other,  maybe deleting one of them broke the connection.  Or maybe it's something completely different; I don't know how to fix it, but the information in the first paragraph might be helpful for debugging, so I"m posting it.

Whatever the fix turns out to be, it'll have to come from SE.  This is beyond what moderators can do.

Comment: Thanks! Your feedback was very helpful. It was indeed a credentials/logins related problem: I accidentally replaced SO login with another, so SO had a different login from the rest. It took me a lot of time to fix it. Sigh!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir How did you fix it eventually?

Comment: @cobra1994 I honestly forgot how it was fixed. It's been 5 years since this happened.